# Find the equations that are tangent to $x^2+x = y$ that also pass through (2,-3)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What should I do here?

I have that $-3 = 2m+b$

So, m= $\frac{-3-b}{2} = \frac{y+3}{x-2}$

I don't know how to proceed

Comment: There are lots of curves tangent to the given one. Presumably you’re looking for tangent *lines*. I suspect that you do really know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you have the equation
$$m(x-2)-3=x^2+x$$
solve this equation for $x$ and set the discriminante equal to Zero and compute $m$.
solve $$m^2-10m-11=0$$ for $m$

Comment: Sorry if this question is obvious, but why should I set the discriminante equal to Zero?

Comment: A quadratic equation (an equation of degree $2$) has a double root if and only if the discriminant equals zero, i.e., https://web.warwick.ac.uk/AEAhelp/glossary/glossaryParser.php?glossaryFile=./Double%20root.htm

Comment: and the discriminant is $m^2-10m-11$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Straight lines which pass through $(2,-3)$ have equation
$$y+3=t(x-2),\quad t\in\mathbf R$$

Such a line is tangent to the curve $\;y=x^2+x$ if and only  if the abscissæ equation for intersection points:
$$t(x-2)-3=x^2+x\iff x^2+(1-t)x+2t=0$$
has a double root.

Answer (score 0):

Find an equation of the line tangent to the graph of the equation $y(x)=x^2+x$ and is passing through the point $(2,-3)$.

Take the derivative of $y$ (with respect to $x$): $y'(x)=2x+1$.

To find the slope of the line at the point $(2,-3)$ which is tangent to the curve $y=x^2+x$, substitute $x=2$ into $y'(x)$: 
$$
m = y'(2) = 2(2)+1=5. 
$$ 
An equation of a line is of the form $y=mx+b$. You know that the equation of this line should be $y=5x+b$. So to find $b$, substitute in $(2,-3)$ because this line must pass through the point $(2,-3)$: 
$$
-3 = 5(2)+b.
$$
So $b=-13$, and an equation of the line that you are looking for must be 
$$
y = 5x-13. 
$$

Comment: Here you are assuming that y passes through (2,-3)

Comment: Yes. Furthermore, this technique above uses the fact that you know how to take the derivative of a function. The other two answers give you a technique without taking the derivative of a function at all.